# Oracle: What SQL for "show error" command?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

When compiling a package or stored procedure in SQL*Plus, `show errors` is used to display any errors from the last compilation.

What is the equivalent SQL query to fetch this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to look at one of the _ERRORS views - either USER_ERRORS, ALL_ERRORS, or DBA_ERRORS. For example:

```
SELECT *
  FROM DBA_ERRORS
  WHERE OWNER = 'YOUR_SCHEMA' AND
        NAME = 'WHATEVER'
  ORDER BY SEQUENCE
```

[Docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1077.htm#REFRN20065).